# How do I go about writing a proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I've decided to self-study math to conquer some old fears--I'm pretty new to the idea of proving overall, and I am stuck on this:  *Explain why there are no real numbers that satisfy the equation: $$|x^2 + 4x| = -12.$$

I've tried to do a proof by induction; but I'm wondering whether this is the right way to approach this, and I frankly do not know how to word it at all. What should I do?

Comment: Isn't it enough to say that $\lvert x^2+4x\rvert\geqslant0>-12$?

Comment: I would suppose so? I'm a bit pedantic if it explains anything!

Comment: How did you plan to prove a property of all real numbers by induction? What were you inducting on, $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: Yes, in order to then say x+1 is also true.

Comment: Induction does not work in the reals. We have no successor of a real number. You could however try to prove something for the interval $[0,1]$ and then, if it is true for $x$, then also for $x-1$ and $x+1$. This would be similar to an induction proof.

Comment: Duly noted, I see how it can function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute value of a real number cannot be negative, hence the equation cannot be solvable.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: @thunders: Given that you are new to reasoning like this, it may seem like a trick question. However, much in mathematics involves logical relationships independent of calculation, and when you get a better feel for the reasoning, this question will seem less tricky. It is often that an equation might have no obvious computational or algebraic method of solution, so one is led to consider "big picture" ideas in an attempt to gain at least partial information about any possible solutions. For example, $\frac{x^4+x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=2$ has no solution because the left side has to be less than $1.$

Comment: The explanation is definitely reassuring; I've been prone to think only of calculation in the past.